# How to find out MPI vendor

Tags: linux, mpi

How do I find out what MPI (MPICH, OpenMPI, etc) is installed?

MPI location (returned by `which mpiexec`) is cryptic and does not hint a vendor.

`mpiexec --version` returns

```
mpiexec version 1.1.8
```

`mpiexec -h` also does not mention the vendor.

Comment: Does your particular flavor of Linux use the `update-alternatives` mechanism for managing this kind of thing?

Comment: There is no macro or so in the standard. Could be that some vendors have a custom way to detect this.